# How to Treat an incorrect inputed date and Password Complexity?

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, passwords

I'm developing a Powershell script where an IT Support must populating many fields.

Like Name, Surname, Description, E-mail, password and Account expires (dd/mm/yyyy)

1-Here I treat an date:

```
$Date = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the end of contract date - dd/mm/yyyy'
Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $SamAccountName -DateTime $Date -Server (Get-ADDomain).PDCEmulator
```

If the date is entered correctly, the script works. But if a non-existent date is entered, example 31/02/2020, it gives an error:

Set-ADAccountExpiration: Cannot bind parameter 'DateTime'. Cannot convert value "31/02/2020" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. "

At C:\Users\Paull\Documents\tests\Versions\Create_user_account.ps1: 58 char: 61

- ... ccountExpiration -Identity $SamAccountName -DateTime $Date -Server ...
- 
- CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADAccountExpiration], ParameterBindingException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId: CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountExpiration

2 - Another issue is the password. The script works fine, but if you enter the password with few characters, null or from the history.

Here how I treat the password:

```
do {
$secpass = Read-Host "Type your password" -AsSecureString
$secpass2 = Read-Host "Confirm password" -AsSecureString
$secpass_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secpass))
$secpass2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secpass2))
}
while ($secpass_text -cne $secpass2_text)
Write-Host "Passwords match." -F green
```

If the password is entered correctly, the script works. If no, it gives an error:

"New-ADUser : The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain. ADPasswordComplexityException"

I would like that when typing a non-existing date, write, 31/02/2020 (dd/mm/ yyyy), **Incorrect date**.
And when entering a password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain, show a warning that **the password is not OK**. I don't want red code errors on the screen.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example checking the date and password complexity.

Dates are not so tricky:

```
#
# something to check for dates
#
$date = '28/02/2020'
# uncomment next line to fail
# $date = '31/02/2020'
if ([string]$date -as [DateTime])  
{
    Write-Output "$date is valid"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "$date is invalid"
}
```

For password complexity, I'd suggest using "try catch" to detect this exception.

```
try
{
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "badpass" -AsPlainText -Force
    New-ADUser -name 'ausername' -AccountPassword $password
}
# catch the specific exception
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException]
{
    Write-Output 'The password does not meet complexity requirements'
}
# deal with the others some other way
catch
{
    Write-Output ('Another problem occurred.  Error {0}' -f $_.Exception)
}
```

Otherwise, to try to work it out based on the password policy could get complicated, below is a simple example that takes into account the default domain complexity and length policy, but it can't take into account history as the script will not have knowledge of previous passwords I assume.

If you're using fine grained password policy then it would need adjustment, too.

```
#
# something to check for passwords
#
$secpass_text = 'test'

if ($null -eq (Get-Module -listavailable activedirectory))
{
    # handle problem, next step required AD module.
}
$policy = Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy

$complexityRulesMet = 0
if ($policy.ComplexityEnabled)
{
    # assume 3 in 4 complexity
    if ($secpass_text -cmatch '[a-z]') { $complexityRulesMet += 1 }
    if ($secpass_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') { $complexityRulesMet += 1 }
    if ($secpass_text -match '\d') { $complexityRulesMet += 1 }
    if ($secpass_text -match '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\\{}|;'''':",./<>?\[\]]') { $complexityRulesMet += 1 }
}
else
{
    # domain doesn't enforce complexity requirement
    $complexityRulesMet = 4
}

if($secpass_text.Length -ge $policy.MinPasswordLength -and $complexityRulesMet -ge 3)
{
    Write-Output "Password is valid"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Password is invalid"
}
```

Comment: I'm only using 2 of the 4 (a-z and /d), but the variable is 3. at:
if($secpass_text.Length -ge $policy.MinPasswordLength -and $complexityRulesMet -ge 3)
It's weird! how to solve?

Comment: missed escaping part of the regex - the section +-= was being treated as all the ascii chars between + and =.  There's probably similar errors in the regex handling I haven't looked too deeply.  I'd recommend sticking to the try/catch approach as that will use the built in password complexity matching process.  Edited to fix this specific problem.